# Remove duplicates and elements matching substring from Javascript array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array with email addresses such as follows:

```
var arr = [{"Element" : "email@mhh.chs.com"}, {"Element" : "email@gmail.com"}, {"Element" : "email2@yahoo.com"} , {"Element" : "email@gmail.com"}]
```

I am trying to figure out the most efficient way to make this array unique and also filter on the email address to remove any with mhh.chs.com. Can this be done in one line asynchronously for both remove duplicates and removing matching substrings? I was looking into filter array and also set but couldnt find anything to do both at once asynchronously.

Comment: That array is unique.

Comment: I updated it to create a duplicate and to specify in one line to be exact.

Comment: *"Can this be done in one line?"*: Sure. A lot of JavaScript can be written in one (long) line. Whole programs can be written on one line...

Comment: everything can be done with one line of code, the question is, do you want that for clarity?

Comment: Well I have been looping through the array to do this all but I felt there has to be a more efficient way.

Comment: It can be done in one line, but one line is ambiguous, and a useless goal at best. If you instead wanted it to be done in one loop, that's a more interesting/useful goal. There's nothing you cant do in "one line" by simply removing line breaks from your code.

Comment: How could you do it without visiting *all* elements? You'll have to visit all elements... so there's your loop...

Comment: `asynchronous` is unrelated to your current goals. Nothing you are asking for is asynchronous

Comment: Asynchronous would mean it filters to remove the substring elements at the same time its removing duplicates such that its looping once through all elements efficiency wise right? unless i am misunderstanding.

Comment: You're looking for simultaneously, aka one loop.

Comment: "Asynchronous" has a very different meaning in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can check multiple conditions within a `filter()` callback. The solution below passes a `new Set()` as second argument to `filter()` which will be set as `this` value in the callback function (for non-arrow functions).

So the the `filter()` callback below first checks if the email not ends with the string `"@mhh.chs.com"`. It then checks if the email is already in the set. If it isn't it will be added and a truthy value (`this.add()` returns the Set instance) will be returned.

```js
var arr = [{"Element" : "email@mhh.chs.com"}, {"Element" : "email@gmail.com"}, {"Element" : "email2@yahoo.com"} , {"Element" : "email@gmail.com"}]

console.log(
  arr.filter(function ({ Element: email }) {
    return !email.endsWith("@mhh.chs.com") // remove @mhh.chs.com emails
        && !this.has(email) // remove duplicate emails
        && this.add(email); // add email to the set and return a truthy value
  }, new Set()) // pass a new Set instance as this argument
);
```

There is no reason to do this operation asynchronously. If you array is really large you might consider delegating the operation to a [Web Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers), but otherwise I would just keep your code simple and synchronous.

Alternatively you could simplify the `filter()` callback, and move the unique checking logic into a separate helper.

```js
var arr = [{"Element" : "email@mhh.chs.com"}, {"Element" : "email@gmail.com"}, {"Element" : "email2@yahoo.com"} , {"Element" : "email@gmail.com"}]

const isUnique = createIsUnique();
console.log(
  arr.filter(({ Element: email }) => !email.endsWith("@mhh.chs.com") && isUnique(email))
);

/**
 * Creates a function that accepts 1 argument. The function
 * returns true for every argument that is passed for the
 * first time. If an argument has been passed before, false
 * is returned.
 *
 * Argument equality is determined by Set.
 *
 *     const isUnique = createIsUnique();
 *
 *     isUnique(1);   //=> true
 *     isUnique(1);   //=> false
 *     isUnique("1"); //=> true
 *     isUnique(NaN); //=> true
 *     isUnique(NaN); //=> false
 *     isUnique({});  //=> true
 *     isUnique({});  //=> true (different object, same content)
 */
function createIsUnique() {
  const items = new Set();
  return function (item) {
    const isUnique = !items.has(item);
    if (isUnique) items.add(item);
    return isUnique;
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that this solution does not work on IE because: IE does not support [object destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring), IE does not support [`String.prototype.endsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith), [`Set.prototype.add()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/add) returns `undefined` (falsy) in IE which causes an empty result.

Comment: Fortunately, not even IE supports IE

Answer (score 0):

A simple loop *is* the most efficient solution to your question. Don't try and obfuscate your own code.

```js
var arr = [{Element: 'email@gmail.com'},{Element: 'email2@yahoo.com'}, {Element: 'email@mhh.chs.com'}, {Element: 'bob@yahoo.com'},{Element: 'email@gmail.com'}, {Element: 'email2@yahoo.com'}];

// Holds the emails
const emails = [];

// Loop over the array
for (let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

  // Get the email
  const { Element: email } = arr[i];

  // If the condition matches remove the object
  if (emails.includes(email) || email.includes('mhh.chs.com')) {
    arr.splice(i, 1);
  }

  // Add the email to the emails array
  emails.push(email);
}

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score -2):

You can get the unique emails by using [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to extract all `Element` property values and [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) with [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

Then, use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter out the emails where the domain is `"mhh.chs.com"`.

Map over the final result and extract the item in `arr` with the corresponding `Element` property value.

```js
var arr = [{"Element" : "email@mhh.chs.com"}, {"Element" : "email@gmail.com"}, {"Element" : "email2@yahoo.com"}]

var result = [...new Set(arr.map(e => e.Element))].filter(e => !e.endsWith("@mhh.chs.com")).map(e => arr.find(f => f.Element == e))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: I believe the asker couldn't piece together how to chain both in a single line, which the answer solves, not that they wanted a method to do both